# Possible to receive the TLS server certificate chain on demand?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate

I am working on an M2M application where data volume is strictly limited and the mobile client has to set up at TLS connection frequently. Is there a standard way - or best practice - for the client to cache the server certificate chain such that the server does not need to send the entire chain on each connection setup?
I can think of a server that does not send along the (optional) certificate chain. The client proceeds as usual if it holds the chain in its local cache. But then, once the server certificates expire, the client must somehow tell the server that it has to send along the new chain.

Is there a possibility to configure popular TLS implementations in apache or ngix in the way described above?

Thanks very much for your help!
Uli

Comment: Both Apache and nginx support TLS session resumption (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Resumed_TLS_handshake) in order to avoid the overhead of a full handshake, are you able to use this in your client?

Comment: Yes, we are looking into session resumption. However, we are talking about devices that connect with the server several times a day, and I would like to prevent the devices exchanging the certificate chain for about a week. Thus, when using session resumption, the server would need to store the session state for potentially thousands of devices over one week time. I doubt that apache or nginx can handle that, but I do not have first-hand experience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way for the client to request the chain from the server on demand. There is a way to have a URL inside a certificate where it can get the issuers certificate, but then the client has to extract this URL and download the certificate on demand. Some desktop browsers do this, but most other SSL stacks don't.

But if client and server support session reuse, then the server has only sent the certificate and chain for the first connection in the session, but not when resuming a session.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Indeed, it seems to be difficult to tell the server when to send the certificates along. I was hoping that a first failed connection attempt because of missing certificates would trigger the server to send along the certificate chain in a second connection attempt. After all, there is a TLS error message that indicates missing certificates.

Comment: There is no TLS error message indicating missing certificates. There is only the "unknown ca" alert but some clients just close (handshake failed). Also, it would require that the server can somehow detect that the same client connects again to send the full chain on retry.